# How to pass the form field scope correctly in feature file of karate framework?

Tags: cucumber, karate

In feature file i passed 
And form `field grant_type = 'client_credentials'`
And form field `scope = '/api'`

after posting the method it is reflecting as `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=**%2Fapi**`   in request message

Expected as

```
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=**/api**
```

could anyone help on this issue how to pass the form field scope in feature file for the `value ='/api'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate is doing the right thing, it is URL-encoding the parameters. Maybe you meant to do `* method post` - then you won't see it in the URL and get confused.

If your server side is not able to handle `scope=**%2Fapi**` it may be a bug in your server.

EDIT: as was discovered, the issue was a very old version of Karate was being used: [How to resolve the HeaderValueException for the post method API call with content type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48002449/143475)

Comment: Yes i used "POST" call and i am getting  "Too many "Content-Type" header values: "[application/json, application/json]" exception in response .could you please help on this ?

Comment: have you tried NOT setting the content-type ? karate will do it automatically when you use `form field`

Comment: yes i tried without passing content type but facing the same issue